# Instructive figure to explain Maximum Likelihood confidence bands / standard errors

Tags: data-visualization, maximum-likelihood, intuition, teaching

I am trying to better understand and explain maximum likelihood estimation. To explain the intuition of many ML aspects I find it easiest to explain them graphically, like for example the ML-based tests LR/Score/Wald:

[image: graphic illustration of different ML based tests]

**My question**: Is there a similar sketch to be drawn for the most common/simple (OPG, Hessian, Sandwich) estimators for standard errors/confidence bands?

**Idea**: Intuitively I expect the uncertainty of my point estimate to be captured by the degree of convexity around the max. This fits with the definitions of some of the estimators. But I can't come up with a good way of drawing this

Comment: Good question. I have added a [tag:data-visualization] tag though it does not fit perfectly (so feel free to remove it).